# Error while running rails server, errors while checking the rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to run the rails server.

Unexpectedly I found this errors while checking the version of Rails:

```
C:\>rails -v
Rails 3.2.8
```

**See above command and below command. one is in 'C' drive and other is my project directory**

```
C:\Mukesh\workspace\Rails\tgif_api>rails version
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:187:in `stub_source_index170': uninitialized constant Gem::SourceIndex (NameError)
    from C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:353:in `stub_rubygems'
    from C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:250:in `replace_entrypoints'
    from C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
    from C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
    from C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from C:/Mukesh/workspace/Rails/tgif_api/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

I already tried system update and running `bundle install`. While executing `bundle install`, it is repeatedly showing `try gem install rake` even though I have already successfully installed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update Bundler: `gem update bundler`